# is it possible to override global body style in react function component

Tags: css, reactjs

I want the component which will embedded in iframe using the independent body style, so I defined the body style in the react component, but the component just using the global css style. the component css defined body are invalid, is it possible to override the global body style? this is the style defined in component:

```
body {
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
```

this is the global body style:

```
body {
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

this is the google chrome render result:

[image]